# I still have an Xbox 360, but how do I get it working?

Tags: power-supply, remote-control, video-game-console

We're talking about this because I own one, roughly dating back 10 years ago when I got it for X-mas. It's an S [slim] model, and after many years of disuse (I believe as of 2016, the same year the 360 was discontinued, or probably 2017), I lost its power supply and all the controllers I used with it. I wanted to get back on the console to play music, but without any of these it still remains dead. The A/V cable remains, however.

[image]

At first I looked everywhere for the power supply, and much to my horror it's vanished forever. I even tried using every 2-pin DC wire to try to get it working, but I quickly realized it actually needs a special adapter in consistence with the power supply (which again I do NOT have). To blame this, I would have to struggle through several resources for the available components, and I'm not sure where to start.

Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you need?: https://www.retroxboxkopen.nl/xbox-360/xbox-360-original-microsoft-controller-wireless-wit-budget and https://www.retroxboxkopen.nl/xbox-360/xbox-360e-ac-adapter-gen-3?

Edit: updated using OP's edits

Comment: Umm.... well, the controller's correct as it works with all models, but not the power supply in general (that's for the ORIGINAL model). The console in question is an X360 S, which has Kinect support. For better accuracy, I'll be editing the original post to include an image of what it looks like.

Comment: Also, I would not try to find things on a foreign source. Is there somewhere else region-friendly?

Comment: Bump...????????

Comment: Hmm, I see... But I only could find stuff in a Dutch store, I don't know why (maybe because Google knows I shop at Dutch shops)

Comment: Well at least someone else might be able to help me and figure this out, perhaps?

Comment: Maybe. This SE is not that popular though, so that can get tricky.

Comment: Okay, so I just found the power supply and its associated wiring. However, since I do not have any compatible controllers I’ll try using it the weird way via a PC mouse. But I’m not sure if that seems practical, does it?

Comment: Welp, the mouse didn't work. I ordered a controller off of eBay, so it should get here no later than November 2.

Comment: Mouse isnt that practical indeed :)